# /var/www/html/login" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, permissions

I do not have the /html/login
file at all.

Does anyone have one so can I fix this error

error.log:
`18:52:25 [crit] 521#521: *3980 stat() "/var/www/html/login" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 120.77.145.186, server: _, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.0"`

Comment: Thisis strange at several levels. If the file doesn't exist, the error should not be "permission denied", but "no such file". Also, you can easily create this file with `touch /var/www/html/login` or `chmod SUITABLEPERMISSIONS /var/www/html/login` to avoid this particular error. However, the question is why 120.77.145.186 accesses this file and if a certain content is expected.

Comment: I added the folder and i get these errors now https://pastebin.com/Pv6jGnky

Comment: Looks like /var/www/html doesn't have proper permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Check the folder's owner.
Probably you create this folder by root user or non "www-data" user.

```
root@domain:/var# chown -R www-data:www-data www
```

or

```
root@domain:/var/www# chown -R www-data:www-data html
```